# Better plot_bloch_multivector within Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit

I'd like the plot_bloch_multivector function (or some other function that I can use in Qiskit) to display a Bloch sphere in a way that makes it clear whether the arrow points toward the front of the sphere or toward the back of the sphere. As it is, the display of |-> can be mistaken for an arrow that's undergone an ry(pi/4) and rz(p/4) operation from |0>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normally it should always label x,y. Can you provide a picture of your output looks like. Normal way to fix it, is just reinstall qiskit-terra. Or just imagine it, because it only got one position of view.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
from qiskit.visualization import plot_bloch_multivector
%matplotlib inline

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)
qc.x(1)

state = Statevector.from_instruction(qc)
plot_bloch_multivector(state)
```

[image]

Comment: This is how Qiskit draws |->: [link](https://users.drew.edu/bburd/solid.png), but I'd like to draw |-> with a dotted line, or something similar indicating a backward-pointing arrow: [link](https://users.drew.edu/bburd/dotted.png)

Comment: @bburd good idea, I will request a issue and pr about this.

Comment: @bburd https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/8202#issue-1275923578

Comment: @bburd current solution is you can make change of https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/4b9e21efe7e50080429f75382c7dce9c1a690e87/qiskit/visualization/bloch.py#L600, to add any parameter that is allowed for ``FancyArrowPatch``

Comment: @bburd accept answer will help a lot, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to accept an answer. How can I do that?

Comment: @bburd https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979/1204878

Comment: Done. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Qiskit, but within [Qutip](https://qutip.org/docs/latest/index.html) you can draw a Bloch sphere using the [bloch3d](https://qutip.org/docs/latest/guide/guide-bloch.html).
In bloch3d, there’s perspective, ie. dots which are farther away appear smaller.

This might help.